# Is the Force divided between its users?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

The 'Darth Plagueis' all but confirms that with the Rule of Two, the dark side of the force is concentrated in the two Sith. Does this mean that the Jedi have less to draw on? Or was this comment innacurate,and the Force is infinite?